# android button event listener does not work

Tags: android

I know this is the basic stuff but I couldn't figure it out. Here is my code:

```
public class test extends Activity{

     private static final String TAG = "test";
     private Button Test;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.v(TAG,"onCreate is called.");

        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Test= (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Test);


        Test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.v(TAG, "onClick Entered.");
                // Perform action on click
            }
        });

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

I can see the first log "OnCreate" but the button click event listener doesn't seem 
to work because I can't see "OnClick Entered". Where did I do wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments / things to try:

- You have your naming conventions backwards. You should be naming your activity in title case, your variables in camel case (e.g. your activity "test.java" should be Test.java, your `Button Test` should be `Button test`). That's not your problem, but just something to keep in mind.
- You're calling `super.onCreate()` twice. I really don't know what effect that has, but it shouldn't be there. You're also calling `setContentView()` twice. One call to onCreate, one call to setContentView is all you should have. EDIT: Apparently three times, per Jems's comment.
- In main.xml, do you have a Button with an id of test? (i.e. `android:id="@+id/test"`)

Comment: I changed the code so onCreate and setContentview are only called once but now I lost the log. LogCat is not stable in terms of capturing debug logs.

Comment: The important thing is, WHERE are you calling them? You should update your answer. How is LogCat not stable?

Comment: I have get rid of the second "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);" and "this.setContentView(R.layout.main);".

Comment: In terms of LogCat, I can't see any log captured while running the code on Emulator. It used to show me at least some logs once I launch the app. I have tried to close it and restart the LogCat from Eclipse, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I finally see the logs. By getting rid of the extra codes, I am now able to see the onClick log.

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `setContentView` twice, the second time after you have set up your on click listener.  This means that the view that you add the listener to is no longer visible, it is replaced with a different instance of the view.  Remove the second `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0):

Where is showTrafficButton defined? Are you sure that shouldn't be:

```
Button showTrafficButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.Test);
```

Comment: I just edited it so the name is Test instead of showTrafficButton